# What is the path to an Android's directory shared among apps?

Tags: android

I would like to send a file by email. The app writes a csv file, and then shares this file via the usual `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`.

For this to work, the file must be readable by other apps (the email app).

I have tried `getExternalStorageDirectory()` but it doesn't work. `/sdcard` works but I feel it is clumsy to use a path like that

What's the best alternative ?

Comment: can you include the code where you actually write the file and access it again?

Answer (score 2):

> It returns null

Perhaps you are running on an emulator for which you did not configure external storage (erroneously referred to as "SD card" in the AVD Manager). I can think of no reason for `getExternalStorageDirectory()` to return `null` on a production device.

> What's the best alternative ?

[Use `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to share the file from your app's internal storage.